Statically and dynamically linked program
i am quite new in unix based systems. I have the task to find a program (i use Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS), which have in the same time both versions installed: statically linked and dynamically linked. I have to compare it’s sizes and list libraries, which are used by dynamically linked one.
I made some research, however what I found is that, it is hard to find nowadays such program, unless you manually download statically linked version of specific app. Is that true? Or is there some programs which are ran in these both ways? If yes, how can I find path of these both versions to compare their sizes? Thanks, for help in advance.

Maintaining a package is difficult enough, I don't think anyone goes around maintaining two versions of the same package with static and dynamic linking. It's going to be one or the other (usually dynamic). If you want to compare the two, you'd have to create binaries yourselves for comparison.

The universe repository does appear to contain statically-linked versions of both bash and zsh (as packages bash-static and zsh-static respectively) as well as a dynamically-linked version of the most well known static executable busybox. If I were doing your assignment I'd probably choose busybox since the implications of screwing it up are likely minimal. Note that these packages do not appear to use the update-alternatives mechanism by default - installing one will remove the other - so you will need to make a copy of the statically-linked /bin/busybox first.
